# Display a debug window on asp.net web page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a ASP.Net web page and I want to create a debug section on the page itself which will show the calls made to and api the return error codes or results etc just like how we have in network debug console.

Comment: Why not just the the debug console you mentioned? Its already in the browser.

Comment: I am trying to make it onscreen just top show API calls made and responses